# Issue with calendarItemsWithExternalIdentifier not thinking it has access to entity types

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to retrieve calendar entries using external calendar ID.  I am doing this for a mac app with target set to 10.11 using xCode 7.1 and code is Swift 2.

When I call the following code

```
let myItems = myEventStore.calendarItemsWithExternalIdentifier(searchString)
```

I get the following messages in the debug output

> 2015-11-04 12:40:03.504 EvesCRM[1447:132129] ERROR: Request access to
>   specific EventKit entity types before attempting to retrieve EventKit
>   objects. 2015-11-04 12:40:03.504 EvesCRM[1447:132129] ERROR: Request
>   access to specific EventKit entity types before attempting to retrieve
>   EventKit objects.

I have checked that the eventstore has authorised the Event and Reminder event types, and have performed this check immediately prior to calling the command, and they have connected and report that access is granted.  All other calls to the same eventstore work as expected, it only seems to be this particular function that is not detecting the entity types.

I have searched for solutions for the past day, but am unable to find anything that helps me move for ward with this.  Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to address this issue.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and solved it by calling always `requestAccessToEntityType:completion:` rather than only checking the status with `authorizationStatusForEntityType:`

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Comment: Worked for me as well in my macOS 10.14 development. Thanks!